# Android, screwy behavior

Tags: android

Cant figure this out (am a noob) but I have a default activity that starts with just one image button, clicking that image button opens the second activity that contains a bunch of image buttons but only one has an onclick, this is the exact code:

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/level1" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:onClick="button_clicked1">
            </ImageButton>
```

in the java file this is my code:

```
public void button_clicked1(View v) {
    //text1.setText("clicked");
    //ib2.setImageResource(R.drawable.level5);
    }
```

The screwy part, if that above function is empty nothing happens but no matter what I put in the above function... for example even a simple settext like the above commented one, and it force closes on me :((

the full java file if you are interested: http://pastebin.com/W4sJUKXH
and the manifest file (as the problem might be there, like I said, am a noobie) http://pastebin.com/yEuG1su7

** Where i think the error is:
In the manifest file I only have declared the second activity, nothing else...

Comment: Anytime you get a force close, please post your LogCat. If we can see this we can know what the problem is. P.S.: You mus have all your activities declared in your android manifest.

Comment: I dont use logcat (not much of an idea how to use it) but found it and here is the text: http://pastebin.com/1cwx5mUn

Comment: Use LogCat. It shows you what the error is then you don't have to come here. Looks like @Nikola found your problem.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for "logcat" am not sure how to use it, just a lot of lines of gibberish (to me)

Comment: Its pretty simple, it's showing you line by line what your phone is doing. When the application fails it shows you why in red.

Comment: I see, that does sound useful, will keep it in mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set id for the ImageViews, this is how you handle many Buttons with one method

```
public void button_clicked1(View v) {

    switch(v.getId())
    {
      case R.id.myfirstimage:
         //do something
        break;
     case R.id.mysecondimage:
       // do something
      break;

  // add more cases


     default:
       // do something if none of the cases is your image view or do nothing
    }

    }
```

Set `setContentView( )` before you do anything with the UI components. (Thats why you get some Exception)

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start_levels_screen);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ib2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    }
```

Comment: I think i did that correctly, here is my java file: http://pastebin.com/W4sJUKXH and here is my xml file: http://pastebin.com/VSWwVjeD

Comment: No, you didnt. The `onCreate()` is faulty.